# Does DKIM works with subdomains?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, smtp, dkim

ISP's recommend you segment your marketing and transactional emails by using different IPs.

I want to start using DKIM, but since DKIM is a domain based reputation system I wonder if signing with the same company.com domain will impact the reputation of transactional emails, since both them and marketing will be signed with the same domain?

Is using DKIM with subdomains possible? Would something like this:

bulk.company.com and transactional.company.com be a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, this is possible. This is a good way. You should really go for it.

But as a side-note: DKIM does not give you a better or worse reputation. The reputation is content based. And Spam is Spam even if you sign it with DKIM (or send it with a different domain).